# Cron job php para envio de mail masivo

Tags: php, phpmailer, batch, cron

He realizado un pequeño programa en php que consulta quien cumple años en el día de hoy y le envía un correo de felicitación a las personas que arroja la consulta, con PHPMailer, todo funciona perfecto, ahora quiero automatizarlo, y quiero crear un cron job, pero no funciona el ejecutable, no se que me falta, este es mi archivo .bat:

```
 C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\birthday\Views\Mail\mailer.php
```

Se supone que al ejecutar el archivo haga la consulta y envie los mail, eso pasa cuando cargo la pagina php con el navegador, las rutas son correctas, pero simplemente no pasa nada al ejecutar el .bat, estoy en windows 10 que es un equipo de la compañía.

Agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

Comment: El problema es que el archivo mailer.php tiene un require para la clase PHPMailer Autoload.php; lo probé con el cmd y eso es lo que sucede; por lo menos ya se porque es el error, ¿alguno sabe como incluir varios archivos, o que cargue los require para que funcione?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el directorio en el que se ejecuta tu script.

Digamos, si en el web se ejecuta desde `C:\xampp\htdocs` entonces tu archivo `.bat` debería tener algo así:

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\birthday\Views\Mail\mailer.php
```

También debes poder indicar una ruta de ejecución al crear el cron.

Comment: Sigue sin servirme, lo abri con el cmd y sale esto   
                                      
                                      
        C:\xampp\htdocs\birthday\Views\Mail\mailer.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>PHPMailer - GMail SMTP test</title>
</head>
<body>
PHP Warning:  require(../../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\birthday\Views\Mail\mailer.php on line 11

Comment: El script tiene un require, en el que llamo la librería, y por eso no ejecuta no la encuentra cuando lo ejecuto en el .bat, ¿no hay forma de ejecutar el que requiere a la vez, o algo así?

Comment: No, el require es relativo a la ruta en la que se ejecuta el script... ¿Dónde está PHPMailerAutoload.php en tu disco duro?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\birthday\PHPMailer\PHPMailerAutoload.php esa es la ruta; el require en el documento mailer.php va asi:   require '../../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';  en la linea 11 ahi es donde marca el error.  Probé corriéndolas ambas pero solo corre uno a la vez.

Comment: Entiendo, prueba cambiando primero al directorio `cd C:\xampp\htdocs\birthday\Views\Mail` y corre desde ahí el script mailer.php. Con eso al regresar dos directorios atrás el script estará en `C:\xampp\htdocs\birthday` y podrá encontrar el archivo señalado en el include...

Comment: Gracias genio, esa era la solución, lo que hice fue primero ir a la ruta y luego si ejecutar el script: asi : cd C:\xampp\htdocs\birthday\Views\Mail
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\birthday\Views\Mail\mailer.php ....  Gran aporte gracias, como siempre era algo sencillo, pero el que no sabe es como el que no ve.